# passing arraylist with JsonJavaObject into method from SSJS

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

On an XPage I have in a viewScope an arraylist with json objects which I want to submit to a managed bean:

```
function createPersons(){
    var json:java.util.ArrayList = viewScope.get("persons");
    personBean.createPersons(json);
}
```

here is an example of the viewscope content:

```
[0] 
area    Compliance
mandatory   true
newArea false
person  Patrick Kwinten/Web
prio    2
[1] 
area    Credits
mandatory   true
newArea false
person  Patrick Kwinten/Web
prio    2
[2] 
area    Food
mandatory   true
newArea true
person  Patrick Kwinten/Web
prio    2
```

Now I would like to define in my java class the method:

public void createPersons(ArrayList json){
        utils.printToConsole(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + " - createPersons() json");
        utils.printToConsole("size json = " + json.size());
        //todo;
    }

but I get the error message:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
JsonJavaObject cannot be resolved to a type personBean.java

Any advice anyone?

Comment: Did you make sure that the personBean class is in your build path and compiles correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a custom Java object in your view scope instead of relying on the Json serialization. You create a Java class, roughly like this:

```
    public class AreaInfo {
        private String area;
        private boolean mandatory;
        private boolean newArea;
        private String person;
        private int prio;

        public String getArea() {
            return area;
        }
        public void setArea(String area) {
            this.area = area;
        }
        public boolean isMandatory() {
            return mandatory;
        }
        public void setMandatory(boolean mandatory) {
            this.mandatory = mandatory;
        }
        public boolean isNewArea() {
            return newArea;
        }
        public void setNewArea(boolean newArea) {
            this.newArea = newArea;
        }
        public String getPerson() {
            return person;
        }
        public void setPerson(String person) {
            this.person = person;
        }
        public int getPrio() {
            return prio;
        }
        public void setPrio(int prio) {
            this.prio = prio;
        }


    }
```

Use that one in your ArrayList in the viewscope. You could also consider having a class around the list if you want to fetch e.g. by Area name etc. Makes it much easier to deal with.

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: yes I think you are right. a bit more work because I am not actually interested how the json objects look like, I just want to transfer them. thanks for your guidance!